# For some reason I am getting, 400 Bad Request when trying to call C# method

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I want to call C# POST method using Ajax but for some reason I always get 400 bad request error. Adding code snippets below for better understanding,

This is my file structure,[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uxtp.png).
Below is my code for privacy.cshtml.cs file,

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication2.Pages
{
    public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

        public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }
        
        public IActionResult OnPost() {

            Console.WriteLine("in post");
            return Page();

        }
    }
}
```

below is the error which I am getting,
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6mvl.png)

Comment: There is no controller here.

Comment: @Sfdc I believe you have got it wrong here. Please follow this tutorial to setup your structure the correct way: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages-Step-by-Step-Web-API-Tutorial-for-Beginners.aspx#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20a,suitable%20name%20and%20click%20Add.

Comment: @RahulSharma this is a Razor Pages app (https://www.learnrazorpages.com), not an MVC app. There are no controller classes.

Comment: You need to include  the anti-forgery token in the request: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes I know.